# Using specific prefix for "well-known corporate author" in "alpha" style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

Is this possible with LaTeX and plain BibTeX?:

I have some "well-known corporate author" articles that look (with some tweaking) in an alpha-style bibliography like this (pdflatex):

[image: Part of Bibliography]

Both authors are cited as "**Int**..." as they start with "**International**".
However being well-known institutions, I'd like to change the first "**Int**" to "**CIE**", and the second "**Int**" to "**ICC**", because that's usually associated with those institutions.

Specifically note that *I want BibTeX to auto-assign the suffix* (like "04b" or "10") while only specifying the prefix ("CIE", "ICC") that is usually composed from the author's name.

Is this possible with plain LaTeX and bibtex?

My bibtex file contains:

```
@misc{cielab_xyz:CIE_15_2004,
    author = {{International Commission on Illumination}},
    publisher = {International Commission on Illumination},
    title = {{CIE} 15: {T}echnical {R}eport: {C}olorimetry, 3rd edition},
    howpublished = {Online: \url{https://cielab.xyz/pdf/cie.15.2004\%20colorimetry.pdf}},
    year = "2004",
    note = "[Online; Stand 23.~Oktober 2019; Nicht mehr verfügbar am 8.~November 2019]",
    annote = "ISBN 3 901 906 33 9"
}

@manual{ICC.1:2010,
    organization = {International Color Consortium},
    title = {Specification {ICC.1:2010} (Profile version 4.3.0.0)},
    number = {ICC.1:2010},
    year = "2010",
    month = 12,
    note = "[Online: \url{http://www.color.org/specification/ICC1v43_2010-12.pdf}; Stand 15.~November 2011]"
}
```

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.

Comment: Adding a `key` it fixed the `@manual`, but it did not fix the `@misc`.